# Specifying domain in zend view url-helper

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect

My application has two modules Product module and Blog module. Both modules use the same DB. There are two domains: the first pointing to the Product Module (www.mainsite.com) and the second to the blog module (www.blog.mainsite.com). There will be multiple links connecting from the Product Module and Blog module.

The issue is that i am using the zend url view helper. But i was not able to specify the domain to that view helper. when i call the view helper it is always returning my current domain. I have checked the zend framework manual, but nothing was found.

Is there any other option in zend to implement the same?

Comment: y cant u cofigure in htaccess

Answer (score 1):

In case of fully qualified URI you should go for:

```
$this->_redirect('http://www.blog.mainsite.com/some/thing');
```

When you are calling the url helper in a view it actually calls route assembler. So I assume you should define two routes for each domain and use the view helper something like that:

```
echo $this->url (array ('action' => 'some', 'controller' => 'thing'), 'routeName');
```

Comment: i dont want to redirect the request, i need the url to be displayed as a link in href's

Answer (score 0):

- You can try this- http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.hostname (not tested)
- You can also just concat `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` with the URL generated by URL view helper.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ServerUrl view helper, along with the "//" notation for inheriting the current URL scheme:

```
echo '//' . $this->serverUrl() . $this->url(/* ... */);
```

Comment: i have tried it earlier, but the the `$this->url()` is already returning the url with the domain so when i append the `$this->serverUrl()` it will actually get doubled..

Comment: Can you provide a code sample showing this? The url() helper should not be doing this by default -- the only reason I'd expect to see the domain doubled is if you forgot the schema or the '//" prefix.